# Use GetVolumeInformationA() in universal app(windows)

Tags: windows, universal

I want to get information about the "c:\", but when I use GetVolumeInformationA() function it say undefined identifier GetVolumeInformationA..

I have already include this header:

```
#include <FileAPI.h >
#include <WinBase.h>
#include <windows.h>
```

and I did see there exist a declaration in `FileAPI.h`, what should I do to use GetVolumeInformationA?

Comment: There are a large number of winapi functions that you cannot use in a UWP app.  Only the ones marked WINAPI_FAMILY_PARTITION(WINAPI_PARTITION_APP).  GetVolumeInformation() is WINAPI_FAMILY_PARTITION(WINAPI_PARTITION_DESKTOP) and therefore only usable from a desktop app.  [There is no substitute](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6de5e697-eb41-4e8e-920c-02b6edb3830c/equivalent-function-of-getvolumeinformation-in-winrt?forum=winappswithnativecode).

Comment: @HansPassant I see in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br205757.aspx that to use all win32 api I should use a Windows Runtime Component as a proxy? So I tried creating a `Windows Runtime Component` and use  GetVolumeInformationA in it, no luck too.. Can I change my UWP to a desktop app and still use xaml to designed the interfaces.